# Linker Error: Undefined reference

Tags: c++, opengl, devil

I'm using the source code in [this article](http://r3dux.org/2010/11/single-call-opengl-texture-loader-in-devil/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=single-call-opengl-texture-loader-in-devil).

I've simply copy and pasted the source to my own project, and Dev-C++ is finding all of the includes; however, when I compile I receive a slew of "linker errors" such as the following:

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to _imp__ilGenImages@8
```

Have I set up my environment improperly somehow? How do I fix it?

Comment: [Don't use Dev-C++](http://www.jasonbadams.net/20081218/why-you-shouldnt-use-dev-c/).

Comment: Yep, I think genpfault is right. Use Code::Blocks if you want a free, quite light, portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked your application against the lib-files included with Devil?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `devil.lib`to your linker dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to link against the static libraries. Read the manual of your compiler to find out how to do that in your case.

Comment: I've added DevIL, ILU, and ILUT.lib to my Linker and I still seem to be getting the same errors. Odd...

Answer (score 0):

Dev-Cpp uses GNU compiler. It could not understand ***.lib*** files. If you still wanna use DevIL, you should build it from sources (avaliable from [their site](http://openil.sourceforge.net/download.php) ; needs some dependices too), use Visual Studio (which is more painless way) or use another library ([SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/) would be good enough).